# adding admobs on my android app

Tags: android-layout, admob

Please assist  with something,I am trying to add admobs on the app but it doesn't show on the app when I run it, but it appears on the android studio preview. How do I fix that?

This code is on the main activity layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d15400"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Score : 1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00:49"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.40" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15*2*1-1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="35.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="29"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp" />

                <!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->



            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

this code is on the questions activity class -

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Maybe there's some other layout code that potentially hides the ad banner. Can you show the full layout code?

Comment: i just did, please look at the full layout code

Comment: Have you added your banned_ad_unit_id properly in your string file.Try changing  ads:adSize="BANNER" to  ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"

Comment: I used the default ad unit id 3940256099942544/630097811, is it ok?